# "As + Sub + Verb"

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, as

As = in the same way as, in the same condition as. 
We use as with subject (S) + verb (V):

- I didn’t move anything. I left everything as it was.
- You should have done it as I showed you.

do we leave out the remaining part after this structure *'As + Subject + Verb'* because of ***ellipses***?

Comment: Makes it clear — what's your doubt?

Comment: @Sam I leave out the remaining part after the structure because of ellipses?

Comment: What 'remaining part'?

Comment: do i need to use 'as I showed you how to do it'?

Comment: You should have done it *how I showed you [to do it]*. If that suits your purpose. But it is not needed. If the main verb is an action verb, you don't have to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

> *You should have done it as* [*I showed you*].

The bracketed element is a comparative clause functioning as complement of "as".

The major distinct feature of comparative clauses is that they are structurally reduced relative to the structure of full main clauses.

In varying degrees, material is left understood that would be overtly present in comparable full main clauses.

In your example, if we fill in the 'missing' bit, we'd get "You should have done it as I showed you it should have been done", which is clumsy and unacceptable, hence the reduction in the comparative clause